# How do I assign Control_R+Menu to the global kxkb switch action?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde-4, xkb

I want to use a combination that avoids alphabetic/punctuation characters because that way I have a consistent physical position on different layouts. <kbd>Control_R</kbd>+<kbd>Menu</kbd> fits that requirement and is also located at a very convenient position.

This combination used to work in KDE 3.5 for the global `kxkb` switch action, or any keyboard action for that matter. In KDE 4, trying to assign `Menu` by pressing the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key always activates the keyboard trap widget's context menu, in this case giving me the **What's this?** context help.

How do I work around that problem? Alternatively, do you have a snippet that I can paste into `$HOME/.kde/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc` and which works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remap the *Menu Key* (like [this post](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=84602#p146036)) :

Put `keycode 135 = F14` (or any other F-key or whatever) to `~/.xmodmap`. This make the computer thinks that the Menu Key is the F14 key.

Then you put a script in the Autostart-folder (usually ~/.kde/Autostart) with the following content :

```
#!/bin/sh
xbindkeys &
```

Make the script executable (chmod +x filename).

Either logout and in again, or just run the script.

OR

Like [this post](http://docs.kde.org/kde3/en/kdebase/faq/panel.html#id2532341), try running the following command (which has the same effect, but I don't remember if this is permanent) :

> xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = F14"

---

If 135 is not the right keycode, referring again the [second link I provided](http://docs.kde.org/kde3/en/kdebase/faq/panel.html#id2532341) :

Try running the command *xev* in a Konsole, and press the Menu key.
Look in the output of xev for *keycode n*, where n is the keycode of the Menu key.

Comment: Accepting you pro forma because it's close enough and the bounty expires tomorrow. Of course I use a modern key mapper instead of xmodmap. The future shall reveal whether I really can dispense with a logical Menu key or whether this will turn out to be a mistake.